# angular module.run can only run inline function

Tags: angularjs

Why bellow code does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('demo',[])
      .factory('myFactory', function(){
        return {foo: function(){return 'bar';}};
      })
      .run(['myFactory', testFn(myFactory)]);

      function testFn(myFactory){alert(myFactory.foo());}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="demo">
  </body>
</html>
```

But bellow code works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('demo',[])
      .factory('myFactory', function(){
        return {foo: function(){return 'bar';}};
      })
      .run(['myFactory', function(myFactory){
        alert(myFactory.foo());
      }]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="demo">
  </body>
</html>
```

In my application the function to run is lengthy so I don't want to put it inline the app.run because it looks really messy. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's `run` block requires a pointer to function, so without creating additional function you can rewrite it to something like that:

```
angular.module('app',[])
      .run(['myFactory', testFn]) // testFn is a pointer to the function.
```

Comment: may you verify the code? it is short anyway. I don't know how to follow your instruction. I guess you mean `.run(['myFactory', testFn])`, and it does not work.

Comment: Sorry I did not get the meaning "testfn is a pointer to the function. Appreciate if you may change [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CjvbRfhQThVo6qh3XzuO?p=preview) to your version to illustrate it.

Comment: Sure, http://plnkr.co/edit/GUUqQrKCtroLoIs4UiVz?p=preview, it a simple optimisation.

Comment: Great. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm a idiot. Fixed by this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('demo',[])
      .factory('myFactory', function(){
        return {foo: function(){return 'bar';}};
      })
      .run(['myFactory', function(myFactory){
        testFn(myFactory);
      }]);

      function testFn(myFactory) {alert(myFactory.foo());}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="demo">
  </body>
</html>
```